# Java Browser, Dynamic string Matcher Pattern

Tags: java, string, dynamic, matcher

I have the following code that uses a specific string and uses the matcher and pattern to draw a link, I also have a method that returns the html code as a string, my problem is that I dont know how to call it so that when the following method runs it uses the dynamic string instead of a static one, I tried using the dynamic string name inside the search but it gave me an error saying that it cannot be compiled since im trying to use a dynamic string instead of a static one, any hints or help would be appreciated, if you need any of my other classes and or methods feel free to ask.

```
String stringToSearch = "<a>www.google.com</a> ";


Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<a>(\\S+)</a>");
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);


if (m.find())
{

  String codeGroup = m.group(1);


  System.out.format("'%s'\n", codeGroup);
   }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a 'design-patterns' question, it is more to do with just knowing how to pass arguments properly into methods.

The [Pattern.compile(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile(java.lang.String)) method takes a string as input. That string doesn't have to be a constant. You can pass that string in as a parameter, I've even put it into a 'helper' method to demonstrate that.

```
public public void someMethod(){
     String stringToSearch = "<a>www.google.com</a> ";
     String matchPattern   = "<a>(\\S+)</a>";

     if (doesMatch(matchPattern,stringToSearch)){
       String codeGroup = m.group(1);
       System.out.format("'%s'\n", codeGroup);
     }
}

public static boolean doesMatch(String pattern, String stringToSearch){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
    return m.find();
}
```

---

to show you what I think you mean...

```
{

    // code... 

     String stringToSearch = getContent(); //might have parameters here or not
     String matchPattern   = "<a>(\\S+)</a>";

     if (doesMatch(matchPattern,stringToSearch)){
       String codeGroup = m.group(1);
       System.out.format("'%s'\n", codeGroup);
     }
}

public static boolean doesMatch(String pattern, String stringToSearch){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(stringToSearch);
    return m.find();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am a bit lost as to what I should do though, I want to replace "<a>www.google.com</a>" with a variable that contains a dynamic string, although your example might answer my question i am a bit lost, for example i have named the dynamic string as getcontent (which returns a string of data) how should I add that to my class?

Comment: added code, but if you don't understand this, then you need to go through some basic java tutorials(free online courses, etc). Because you'll have extreme difficulty being able to continue forward.

Comment: Thanks again, indeed I am missing some basic knowledge as I am a first year student, and I am searching around the web and trying to learn my way up! Thanks again for your reply.